# IndexOutOfBoundsException at at android.text.PackedIntVector.getValue(PackedIntVector.java:75)

Tags: android

I have a profile page under which I have a couple of TextView, EditText, and Spinner. This page is functioning normally but **sometimes it crashes randomly** and I'm unable to understand the reason behind this as the crash seems internal and the stack trace doesn't point to the specific line of code in my activity file.

Issue:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp.uat, PID: 15306
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1, 1
at android.text.PackedIntVector.getValue(PackedIntVector.java:75)
at android.text.DynamicLayout.getLineTop(DynamicLayout.java:1011)
at android.text.Layout.getLineBottom(Layout.java:2407)
at android.text.Layout.getLineBottom(Layout.java:2396)
at android.widget.Editor.drawHardwareAcceleratedInner(Editor.java:2262)
at android.widget.Editor.drawHardwareAccelerated(Editor.java:2202)
at android.widget.Editor.onDraw(Editor.java:2140)
at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:9067)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23889)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22756)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:694)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:700)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:798)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4939)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:4643)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3822)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2465)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9305)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1339)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1348)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:952)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:882)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1322)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

Comment: Would be good to add some of your code. Would help to understand the issue.